# Is it a good practice to use os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)) at the beginning of the file?

Tags: python

I have a script that loads a lot of files in its directory, and this script could be called from any location. I want to know if it is ok to use `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` at the beginning of the file to make things less verbose.

Directory of the script:

```
script/path/
  do_stuff.py
  src/
    ..some files
```

The script is called like that:

```
$ python3 script/path/do_stuff.py
```

So, instead of doing

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'src/..')) as f:
    ...
```

I add `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` after the imports and do:

```
with open('src/..') as f:
    ...
```

Is this considered a good practice? Or should I avoid it in order to avoid complications in more complex projects?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I do see something wrong with it. Namely, the most common use-case of command line tools (calling them with a relative path) will no longer work. Beyond that, changing directory is actually a pretty involved operation that isn’t well supported by all filesystems. This *does* break tools in practice. It’s rare and relatively obscure but it exists, and it’s in fact creating a major headache for a colleague.

Comment: To give an example of what @KonradRudolph is talking about: `python path/to/tool.py ../../inputfile1.dat ./file2.dat`. The relative paths to the input files only make sense relative to the directory from which the tool was launched. So, at the very least, make sure to load all user specified paths *before* changing directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another alternative:

3. Write a function that gives you the correct path for a local file resource:

   ```
   def get_resource_file(path):
       return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   with open(get_resource_file('src/…')):
       …
   ```

As mentioned in my comment, changing the current working directory means you can no longer accept relative paths from user input (unless you first store the original working directory and construct absolute paths from that). This is probably *the* most common scenario of a command line tool:

```
path/to/tool local/path/to/file
```

By contrast, the gain of `cd`’ing away from the user’s working directory is relatively small.